# Make Chrome fullscreen behavior the same as in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer-9

In IE9, when I'm in fullscreen mode, if I move the cursor near the top of the screen, a bar with opened tabs, back/forward buttons, address box... appears:

[image]

However, when I do the same thing in Chrome, it only displays an useless notice "You have gone fullscreen":

[image]

Is there a way to change the behavior in Chrome to the same as in IE? An extension, for example?